# Trying out neo4j grails plugin, but it does not mach the docs

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-orm

I am trying neo4j plugin and I created a simple test as follows:

```
package com.iibs.graph

import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
import com.iibs.graph.Node

public class NodeTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testCRUD() {
        Node.deleteAll(Node.list())

        Node node = new Node(name: "Name")

        node.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        Node found = Node.findByName("Name")

        assert found instanceof Node
        assert found.getName() == "Name"

        assert found.node instanceof org.neo4j.graphdb.Node 
    }
}
```

Based on the documentation: http://projects.spring.io/grails-data-mapping/neo4j/manual/ref/Additional%20Gorm%20Methods/getNode.html
this test is expected to pass without any problems, however I am getting the following error:

```
| Failure:  testCRUD(com.iibs.graph.NodeTests)
|  Assertion failed: 
assert found.node instanceof org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
       |     |    |
       |     null false
       com.iibs.graph.Node(Name)
    at com.iibs.graph.NodeTests.testCRUD(NodeTests.groovy:20)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 1s
```

Am I using the API in a wrong way?

Also, if I changing the last assertion line to:

```
assert found.getNode() instanceof org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
```

The error is different:

```
Failure:  testCRUD(com.iibs.graph.NodeTests)
|  groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.iibs.graph.Node.getNode() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getName(), getId(), setName(java.lang.String), getMongo(), getAll(), getCount()
    at com.iibs.graph.NodeTests.testCRUD(NodeTests.groovy:20)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 2s
```

As shown in the error, one of the proposed solutions is to use **getMongo**. What does it have to do with mongo. Here is my entity:

```
package com.iibs.graph

import groovy.transform.ToString;


@ToString(includes='name')
class Node {

    String name

    static mapWith = "neo4j"

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Latest milestone: compile ":neo4j:2.0.0-M01"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for the plugin have not yet been updated for 2.x - it's the first milestone.

In short, domain instances no longer have a `node` property since we're relying on Cypher internally only. The `id` property of the domain instance refers to the `__id__` property on the node in the graph.

Comment: OK, makes sense. How do I access such functionality as **hasRelationship** on the node? Is the intention is to use lower level API only? Or in other words, how do I get the actual node?

Comment: you can do `instance.cypher('MATCH (self)--(related) WHERE self.__id__={this} RETURN related', [:])`

Comment: I created a new thread as the question is not directly related to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23490581/cannot-find-node-using-graphdatabaseservice-when-it-is-created-in-the-same-test