# Cannot find node using graphDatabaseService when it is created in the same test

Tags: grails, neo4j, grails-orm

as continuation of [Trying out neo4j grails plugin, but it does not mach the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489074/trying-out-neo4j-grails-plugin-but-it-does-not-mach-the-docs)

I have a test now looks like this:

```
package com.iibs.graph

import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
import com.iibs.graph.Node

public class NodeTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    def graphDatabaseService

    void testCRUD() {
        Node.deleteAll(Node.list())

        Node node = new Node(name: "Name")

        node.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        Node found = Node.findByName("Name")

        assert found instanceof Node
        assert found.getName() == "Name"

        org.neo4j.graphdb.Node graphNode = graphDatabaseService.getNodeById(node.getId())

        assert graphNode.instanceOf(org.neo4j.graphdb.Node) == true
    }
}
```

And I am getting an error as follows:

```
| Running 1 integration test... 1 of 1
| Failure:  testCRUD(com.iibs.graph.NodeTests)
|  org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: Node 905482810884096 not found
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.getNodeById(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1088)
    at com.iibs.graph.NodeTests.testCRUD(NodeTests.groovy:22)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
| Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 2s
```

As far as I understand from the mentioned thread, this should be one of the possible ways to get the node. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not as familiar with the grails interface, but write operations like creating a new node frequently require transactions, and you don't have one.  Maybe the transaction that contains the node you're writing doesn't commit prior to you trying to find that node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet (did not test myself, just a braindump):

```
def nodeInstance = ....
nodeInstance.save(flush:true)

String label = nodeInstance.getClass().simpleName
def neoNode = graphDatabaseService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label(label), "__id__", nodeInstance.id)
```

Comment: So, this seem to be working for me:

`String label = found.getClass().simpleName
def graphNodes = graphDatabaseService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(DynamicLabel.label(label), "__id__", found.id)
assert graphNodes[0] instanceof org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
assert graphNodes[0].hasRelationship() == false`

But isn't it suppose to be the same as findById() ?